# Name for the peak of a plateau

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, geography

The highest point; the flatland.

**Ex:** *Summit* is to mountain/hill as _____ is to plateau.

Would *summit* just be acceptable in itself?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A plateau is just a flat table, not a cone. There is no apex.

Comment: *table top*....

Comment: I think the correct word you are looking for is "plateau".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition, "a plateau" consists  of relatively flat terrain that is raised significantly above the surrounding area. If any part of a plateau is raised significantly to form a peak, it won't be considered a part of it. In a nutshell, there are no significant peaks on a plateau.

> - "plateau" or "high plain" or "tableland" - an elevated, comparatively level expanse of land.  [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plateau)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, summit and peak are perfectly understood with respect to mesas and plateaus. And many of them are anything but flat on top. They tend to be craggy and tilted.

Black Mesa Summit -

> The highest point in Oklahoma at 4,973 feet, Black Mesa Summit can be
>   reached with a scenic 4.2-mile hike across landscape unknown in other
>   parts of the Sooner State.

http://www.bestoklahomatrails.com/blackmesatrail.html

Uncompahgre Pleateau - Horsefly Peak

> The Plateau rises from 4,600 feet (1,400 m) at Gateway to over 10,300
>   feet (3,100 m) at the top of Horsefly Peak. The summit is relatively
>   flat with an average elevation of 9,500 feet (2,900 m) that runs
>   southeast to northwest. The summit drops off quickly on the west side
>   and more gradually slopes downward on the east side.

http://www.summitpost.org/uncompahgre-plateau/871513